# ANTLR4: Lexer returning a single token when in a lexer mode

Tags: antlr4

I am attempting to use a lexer mode with ANTLR4 with the following lexer grammar:

```
STRING: '"' -> pushMode(STRING_MODE);
mode STRING_MODE;
STRING_CONTENTS: ~('"'|'\n'|'\r')+ -> type(STRING);
END_STRING: '"' -> type(STRING), popMode;
STRING_UNMATCHED: . -> type(UNMATCHED);
```

- Is there a way to return a single token of type STRING for all the characters captured within the mode and including the characters which caused an entrance to the mode?
- When does the mode end?

I am aware that I can also write the string token like so:

```
STRING: '"' (~["\n\r]|'\\"')* '"';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The `more` attribute will accumulate the matched text into the first token emitted by a non-`more` attributed rule.

For:

```
STRING: '"' -> more, pushMode(STRING_MODE);

mode STRING_MODE;
    STRING_CONTENTS: ~('"'|'\n'|'\r')+ -> more ;
    END_STRING: '"' -> type(STRING), popMode;
```

the text matching the `STRING` and `STRING_CONTENTS` rules is prepended to that of the `END_STRING` rule, resulting in a `STRING`-typed token containing the full text of the string.

2) The 'end' of a mode statement is implied by the first subsequent encounter of

- a parser rule
- another mode statement
- a fragment rule
- EOF

Comment: Was not aware of the more attribute.